# Java Spring Reactive return error message to user OR json of some Object

Tags: java, spring, types, error-handling, project-reactor

My first question, so please be understanding if I miss something.

So I need to do something similar to this image (but working):

```
    @GetMapping("/search")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<?>> findProduct(@RequestBody ProductSearch productSearch) {
        return findProduct2(productSearch)
            .map(products -> new ResponseEntity<>(products, HttpStatus.OK))
            .onErrorResume(IllegalArgumentException.class, error -> new ResponseEntity<>(error, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST));
    }
```

Here I try to send a Mono<List> back to the user if he passed some other validations and no errors processing request. But I would also like to return a 400 and a message back to user indicating why it failed the validations (the message would be a String).
The error I can not get past is the type checking.

This seems like a fairly easy task since HTTP does not care wether it receives object/string (maybe only in the sense of it's MediaType).

I already researched quite a bit on this and I only find one answer that would somewhat fit (although tried others) and that would be changing the "server.error.include-message" setting of spring to "onparam" or "always" but I don't want this here. Mostly because if some unknown error happens it might leak the stacktrace to the user, but there are other reasons.

Another one would be to create an Object similar to this:

```
public class ReturnType {
   private List<ProductEntity>> result;
   private String errorMessage;
}
```

and return it, but I am working in a team so this would be a more complex solution and not what I wanted.

Yet again I stress, I know these are solutions, but for such a simple problem I can not understand why there is not one better.

Thanks to anyone who helps me on this, in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone withe the same doubt.

Try changing the GetMapping annotation:

```
@GetMapping(value="/search", produces={"application/json","text/html"}, consumes="application/json")
```

I think it's self explanatory, but this enables 2 types HTTP mediaTypes to be returned instead of only one, which was the issue.